# Installing and using the ParMetis library

Tags: c++

I am installing ParMetis 4.0.3 but into a non-default directory, with:

```
make config prefix=/My-ParMETIS-Directory/
```

And afterward:

```
make install
```

After that, I get a set of directories in that folder. And to write a program that uses it, I'm supposed to add the 'include "parmetis.h"' in the headline, and also add the 'libraries/binaries'. How exactly do I do the latter?

I'm just trying to get my code to compile now, and doing so I run:

```
g++ test.cpp
```

This is test.cpp:

```
#include<iostream>
#include "include/parmetis.h"

using std::cout;
using std::endl;

int main()
{
    cout << "Test!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I keep getting "was not declared in this scope" for everything/every-line in parmetis.h.

How can I get test.cpp use the other folders/files that were installed?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to provide the location of your ParMetis library to
the compiler, since you have choosen to install the library
not in the default library directories.

```
mpic++ test.cpp -I /My-ParMETIS-Directory/ -I /My-METIS-Directory/
```

**Edit#2:**

What I did to get your code compiling:

1. Download the ParMetis library from webpage to **/tmp**

   ```
   cd /tmp/
   wget http://glaros.dtc.umn.edu/gkhome/fetch/sw/parmetis/parmetis-4.0.3.tar.gz
   ```
2. Unpack archive

   ```
   tar -xf parmetis-4.0.3.tar.gz
   ```
3. Install ParMETIS into directory **/tmp/parmetis**

   ```
   mkdir parmetis
   cd parmetis-4.0.3/
   make config prefix=/tmp/parmetis
   make install
   ```
4. Install METIS into directory **/tmp/metis**

   ```
   cd /tmp/
   mkdir metis
   cd parmetis-4.0.3/metis
   make config prefix=/tmp/metis
   make install
   ```
5. Compile **test.cpp** which is located in /tmp/

   ```
   cd /tmp/
   mpic++ test.cpp -I /tmp/parmetis -I /tmp/metis
   ```

Comment: What should this directory be exactly? I entered exactly that, and it still tells me everything "was not declared in this scope" :( Is it a subdirectory that I should give it? (it  has sub directories such as bin, include, lib etc)

Comment: As an remark: Since parmetis is based on MPI, you need to install an MPI implementation on your system (e.g. OpenMPI) and compile your source file with mpic++ instead of g++

Comment: It should be the some directory you used when you have configured ParMetis before installing: make config prefix=/My-ParMETIS-Directory/

Comment: I do that and it still gives the same problem! :( I tried pretty much everything, including mpicc instead of g++, it always says the same thing: "was not declared in this scope"

Comment: You should use mpic++ like a wrote in the comment above. Nevertheless, I provided you a full step by step example which should be enough to compile your code.

Comment: Thank you for your help, I really appreciate it. I delete all I had, and I repeated all your steps EXACTLY, and I still get the same problem of    "error: ‘comm’ was not declared in this scope" (comm is just one of them). (I'm using mpic++) Why would this happen ! Could it be because of the -I command not being recognized (I'm saying this because it seems whatever I put after the -I, it doesn't complain or respond to anything)? Should it rather point to the bin folder instead or so? I'm running out of ideas :(
Again, thanks a lot for your help!!!

Comment: Can you copy paste the error message, so I can have a look at it ?

Comment: /PM/parmetis/include/parmetis.h:18:19: error: metis.h: No such file or directory |||||
In file included from test.cpp:2:
/PM/parmetis/include/parmetis.h:69: error: ‘idx_t’ was not declared in this scope |||||
/PM/parmetis/include/parmetis.h:69: error: ‘vtxdist’ was not declared in this scope ||||| .... (and it continues for every line in parmetis.h) (|||||=newline)

Comment: Okay, the problem is the first line: error: metis.h: No such file or directory. So you also need to install metis which can be found in the parmetis-4.0.3/metis directory. I updated my answer in point 4. This should finally work :-)

Comment: That worked, thanks!!! I had to also change the #include <metis.h> to #include "../metis/include/metis.h" to make it work. Thanks again!

Answer (score 0):

when you coding wtih C++ ,if you meet question like that :

- ccJjiCo.o: In function `main':
- bsplele.cpp:(.text+0x45e): undefined reference to `METIS_PartMeshNodal'
- collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

you can check the compiler sentence and you should paste the -lmetis at the end of the compilation command.It is useful for me.

my right compilation command is that:g++ -L/home/hadoop/metis/lib -I/home/hadoop/metis/include/ LL_metis.cpp -lmetis